# Groovy programming

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm doing some research on the Groovy programming language, and despite all the information there is out there, I am having a hard time finding some examples of what well-known applications are written in Groovy, or what companies use Groovy. Anyone care to help me out? I'd like to have some information to share at the end of a presentation I am giving tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good list of sites in this quora question - http://www.quora.com/Who-has-deployed-a-medium-large-website-succesfully-on-Groovy-Grails

Answer (score 2):

A showcase of startups built using the Grails web application framework: [**Grails Startups**](http://grails-startups.herokuapp.com/).